# Severe straggler tasks due to Locality Level being "Any" and a Network Fetch on cached RDD

Tags: apache-spark

A cached dataset that has been completely read through - successfully - is being reprocessed.  A small number (typically 2/204 tasks - 1%) of the tasks may fail on a subsequent pass over the same (still cached) dataset.  We are on spark 1.3.1.

The following screenshot shows that - of 204 tasks - the last two seem to have been 'forgotten' by the scheduler.

Is there any way to get more information about these tasks that are in limbo?

[image]

All of the other tasks completed within a reasonable fraction of similar time: in particular the 75% is still within 50% of the median. It is just these last two stragglers that are killing the entire job completion time. Notice also these are **not due to record count skew**

[image]

**Update** The two stragglers did finally finish - at over 7 minutes (over 3x longer any other other 202 tasks) !

```
15/08/15 20:04:54 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 201.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 601) in 133583 ms on x125 (202/204)

15/08/15 20:09:53 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 189.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 610) in 423230 ms on i386 (203/204)
15/08/15 20:10:05 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 190.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 611) in 435459 ms on i386 (204/204)
15/08/15 20:10:05 INFO DAGScheduler: Stage 2 (countByKey at MikeFilters386.scala:76) finished in 599.028 s
```

Suggestions on what to look for /review appreciated.

**Another update**  The TYPE has turned out to be **Network** for those two. What does that mean?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar issue with you. Try increasing `spark.locality.wait`.

If that works, the following might apply to you: 
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-13718#

** ADDED **

Some extra information that I found helpful.

1. Spark will always initially assign a task to the executor that contains the respective cached RDD partition.
2. If Task is not accepted under the locality timeouts [as defined in the spark config](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#scheduling), then it will try NODE_LOCAL, RACK_LOCAL, ANY in that sequence.
3. Regardless if the cached data are available locally (HDFS replicas), Spark will always fetch the cached partition from the node that contains it. It will only re-compute if that executor crashed so the RDD is no longer cached. This will, in many cases, cause a network bottleneck on the original straggler node as well.

Comment: I read the "bug" (which is "not a  bug" according to Sean Owen) report. It **is** helpful to know about that tuning parameter. I will award.

Comment: Thanks - I have also attached a diagram (on the bug that is actually an improvement) that makes it more clear to understand.

Comment: This is interesting info re: locality usage by Spark. Thanks for the insight.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using Spark speculation (`spark.speculation true`)? Spark will identify these stragglers and relaunch then on another node.

Comment: Yes - that may help on the first occurrence of this issue but subsequent jobs get even further delayed because the workers are not recouped.  It is a strange behavior.